# Which pattern should I use to call different functions in the same loops?

Tags: python, design-patterns, wrapper

I often use the same set of nested functions inside which I call different functions. Something with analogous structure to this:

```
data = 'example'
...
for i in range(10):
    # use data here
    another_data='another'
    for j in range(10):
        some_func(i, j, data)

...

for i in range(10):
    # use data here
    another_data='another'
    for j in range(10):
        another_func(i, j, another_data)
```

Which pattern should I use to avoid coping the code?

I tried with decorator, but I didn't know how to pass arguments to `some_func` that were created in inside wrapper function and omit passing arguments them when calling `some_func`.

Comment: `range('10')` → `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function as parameter. No need for a special design pattern.

```py
def some_func(i, j, data):
    pass

def another_func(i, j, data):
    pass

def process_data(data, processor_function):
    for i in range(10):
        # use data here
        another_data='another'
        for j in range(10):
            processor_func(i, j, data)

data = 'example'
process_data(data, some_func)
process_data(data, another_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through a list of functions:

```py
funcs = [some_func, another_func]

data = 'example'
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for func in funcs:
            func(i, j, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used a generator:

```
def some_func(i, j, data):
    pass

def another_func(i, j, data):
    pass

def input_generator(data):
    for i in range(10):
        # use data here
        another_data='another'
        for j in range(10):
            yield i, j, data

data = 'example'

for i, j, data2 in input_generator(data):
    some_func(i, j, data2)
    another_func(i, j, data2)
```